# the_post_thumbnail(array(X,Y)) doesn't work well

Tags: wordpress

The size of my posts’ featured images is 700x400 or more, and in order to display them center-cropped to 300x400 I use :

```
the_post_thumbnail(array(300,400));
```

However this code displays everything except a 300x400 image. Anybody could tell me how to achieve what I want ?

Answer (score 2):

As the function manual says:-

> PLEASE NOTE: The crop does not work in
>   Wp 3.0+. All that is needed for WP
>   3.0+ is the call for the thumbnail to post. Then proceed to media in the
>   dashboard and set your thumbnail to
>   crop to the size you wish to use.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

Comment: Ok, well I tried this too actually. For example if I set 300x300 in **Dashboard > Media Settings > Image Sizes > medium size**, and in my code I do the_post_thumbnail('medium'), I still obtain anything except a 300x300 image.

Comment: Do you want exactly 300x300?. In media settings, these are the maximum width and height for the thumbnail! WP is keeping aspect ratio for images!

Comment: Yes I want precise dimensions because it's for a category page not a single page, and I display many post titles and excerpts with their respective featured images in a clean grid, so I need fixed dimensions for the images you see.

Yet simply specifying the dimensions in the dashboard doesn't do the trick.

I use WP 3.0.4

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://gavinsmith.me/2010/10/multiple-post-thumbnail-featured-image-sizes-in-wordpress/

You can dig a bit further than using only `the_post_thumbnail` and actually create your own image sizes. Then, using `the_post_thumbnail`, you can call the image - but the version you have created `using add_image_size`, as described on that page. Let me know if I lost you there.

Comment: Thanks Gavin. I tried to create a new image size with add_image_size( 'author-thumbnail', 60, 60, true ) and then the_post_thumbnail('author-thumbnail'). That works fine but if for instance I put 200, 100 instead of 60, 60 it doesn't work. I do not obtain a 200x100 image but rather a square image !
(sorry I couldn't comment any more on that post I dunno why)

Answer (score 0):

**try out this**

```
<?php echo the_post_thumbnail(array(32,32)); ?>
```

You can Increase size on desire